# Definir as cores de um ponto em um gráfico scatter do matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estou tratando dados recebidos de um arduino a partir de um arquivo .txt. No codigo, eu gero 4 arrays (X,Y,Z e F), sendo que X,Y e Z são coordenadas e F é a força do sinal.

Gostaria de plotar o gráfico 3D com a função scatter do matplotlib, mas definir a cor de cada ponto a partir dos valores de F. Por exemplo, definir um colormap e colorir cada ponto a partir do respectivo valor no vetor F.

O código abaixo faz o plot 3D das coordenadas, mas todos os pontos são da mesma cor. Como eu posso controlar a cor individualmente de cada ponto?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

def separador(string,sep):
    '''
    Função para ler os valores do Arduino e separá-los em listas
    '''
    lista = []
    k = 0
    j = k
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] in sep:
            j = i
            pal = string[k:j]
            k = j+1
            lista.append(float(pal))
    return lista

file = open('saidas_arduino\scanner_oreo.txt')
output = file.readlines()
file.close()

# distancia ate a mesa e forca do sinal
dist_mesa = float(output[4][0:len(output[4])-1])
str_mesa = float(output[6][0:len(output[6])-1])

# linha em que começa a leitura
line_xyz = 0
for i in range(20):
    if output[i] == 'x,y,z,str\n':
        line_xyz = i+1
        break
    
# salva os dados em vetores
X = []
Y = []
Z = []
F = []
for i in range(line_xyz,len(output)-1):
    linha = separador(output[i],('\n',','))
    X.append(linha[0])
    Y.append(linha[1])
    Z.append(linha[2])
    F.append(linha[3])
    
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
Z = np.array(Z)
F = np.array(F)
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# aqui eu gostaria de definir o colormap pra cada ponto
ax.set_zlim(-20,20)
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

a [documentação](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html), em inglês, indica que o `scatter` pode receber um argumento `c` que será usado para colorir os pontos. Esse argumento pode receber uma cor, sequência de cores, etc. Em particular, se esse argumento receber um vetor de escalares, então esses escalares são passados para um mapa de cores (cmap), gerando um gradiente.

Modificando-se a parte relevante do código:

```
# dados artificiais

rnd = np.random.default_rng()
X, Y, Z, F = rnd.uniform(-20,20, size=(4,20))

# figura

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# aqui eu gostaria de definir o colormap pra cada ponto
ax.set_zlim(-20,20)
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, c=F, cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.show()
```

[image: scatterplot com gradiente]

você pode verificar outras opções de cores neste [site](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) (em inglês).

PS: uma figura 3D é um tipo de visualização que só faz sentido em situações muito particulares, muitas vezes se você plotar os dados em 2D e usar cores, tamanhos e formas para representar as informações que você quer representar em outras dimensões o resultado fica melhor.